# Cloning Spring Application Context in OSGi bundle

Tags: spring, osgi

I have a Spring-enabled OSGi bundle. I'd like this bundle to export a factory-type OSGi service which client software can use to create multiple instances of the application context defined in this bundle.

By default the Spring DM library bundles will automatically scan and create an instance of an application context from any Spring XML configuration found under "META_INF/spring". To avoid this I moved the Spring XML configuration files under a different folder and then tried creating the application context programmatically on demand from the factory class. Unfortunately I ran into issues with Spring schema files not being available on the bundle classpath. I really don't want to embed the required Spring jars within my bundle just to get access to those schemas.

Is there a simpler way to clone Spring application contexts under an OSGi environment?

Comment: How is this "factory-type OSGi service" used?  Is it like myOsgiService.newInstance(), or configure service instances in a config file and let the clients reference them?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your problem in detail but if you just want to load the application-context from a different location than META-INF/spring you can define this in the MANIFEST.MF file using 'Spring-Context', e.g. for files in the root folder

```
Spring-Context: /application-context-core.xml,/application-context-osgi.xml
```

See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.2.1/reference/html/app-deploy.html#app-deploy%3aheaders) for further information.

Comment: The problem is that I need to create multiple instances of the same application context. If I have Spring DM create the application context there will only be one instance.